# Is there a way to prevent iOS6 to kill the specific task process?

Tags: ios, ipad

I know that iOS has its own task management method and users may never need to care about the processes background. But my requirement is to ALWAYS keep a program alive, it cannot be killed under any circumstance.

Is there a way to do this like "LOCK" or something else function already existed? I'm using iPad4 ios6.01 system.

Thanks

Comment: There is no way to keep a program open forever. That's too unsecure to allow anyone to do. You can run the program in the background but only for the life of a particular task which even then is limited based on available system resources.

Comment: @Ryan Poolos yes, iOS automatically kills the process to release the resource, but my requirement is DO NOT kill this one, you can kill any other one but never this one, I'd like to adjust the way iOS "choose" the target process to kill. You mentioned security issue, I don't think keep the program alive all the time raise security issue. If any, you can prompt user to re-input the credentials instead of kill the program.

Comment: I'm telling you whether you think its a security risk or not, Apple does. and it is *impossible* to keep a task alive beyond the limits Apple has set. Based on what you need there are options like for push notifications and what not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible. (Nor should it be if you think about it. What's to stop *every* app from saying that it can't be killed?)

The closest you can get is for things like VoIP apps that do run in the background and automatically respawn when they die.

The alternative is to work like every other app: when your app goes into the background you save state so you can restore if it gets killed. iOS 6 even has the state restoration functions.

Answer (score 1):

**Short and simple**
No, there is no way to make your App "unkillable".

**A bit longer**
If your App requires to receive location updates while it is running in background, you can use the standard way Apple offers to do so.

Two other options are: your App is an VoIP application (afaik they also get autostarted on system boot) or you're playing audio in the background. Without knowing too much details about how iOS handles such Apps, they might get killed if the iDevice runs out of memory (or the user kills it). But you probably already knew that.

However, as you already mentioned, iOS manages everything on it's own and will kill Apps that run in background to free memory. Additionally as we all know, a user might kill your App at any time using the task switcher of iOS.

And don't try to use the described methods just to run tasks in the background. If Apple finds out about it, your App will be rejected/removed from the App Store quickly.